# Save/Load Dialog text files

Tags: c++, winapi, load, save

I've created a dialog box with an edit box and two buttons. A save and load button.

When save is clicked I want to save the text in the edit box to a txt file, and load, load the txt file into the editbox. Right now the save/load buttons do not seem to be working. The save button seems to create a file called 'u' instead of saving to the selected file and the load button doesn't do anything after a file is selected. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <commdlg.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "resource.h"
using namespace std;

// Globals
HWND ghMainWnd = 0;
OPENFILENAME ofn;


// Handles
static HWND hEditBox    = 0;
static HWND hSaveButton = 0;
static HWND hLoadButton = 0;

// Contains file.
char szFile[100];

void save()
{

    char text[260];

    GetWindowText( hEditBox, text, 260 );

    ofstream saveFile( szFile, ios_base::binary );

    int length = strlen( text );
    saveFile.write( (char*)&length, sizeof(length) );
    saveFile.write( text, length );

}

void load()
{

    char text[260];

    ifstream loadFile( szFile, ios_base::binary );

    int length = 0;
    loadFile.read((char*)&length, sizeof(length));

    loadFile.read( text, length );

    text[length] = '\0';

    SetWindowText( hEditBox, text );
}

BOOL CALLBACK
WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{

    ZeroMemory( &ofn , sizeof( ofn ) );

    ofn.lStructSize     = sizeof( ofn );
    ofn.hwndOwner       = hWnd;
    ofn.lpstrFile       = szFile;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0]    = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile        = sizeof( szFile );
    ofn.lpstrFilter     = "All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex    = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle  = "Open/Save File Dialog";
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle   = 0;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.Flags           = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

    switch( msg )
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        hEditBox    = GetDlgItem( ghMainWnd, IDC_EDIT );
        hSaveButton = GetDlgItem( ghMainWnd, ID_SAVE );
        hLoadButton = GetDlgItem( ghMainWnd, ID_OPEN );
    return true;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch( LOWORD( wParam ) )
        {
        case ID_SAVE:
            GetSaveFileName( &ofn );
            save();
        return true;

        case ID_OPEN:
            GetOpenFileName( &ofn );
            load();
        return true;
        }
    return true;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow( hWnd );
    return true;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage( 0 );
    return true;
    }

    return false;
}

INT WINAPI
WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR cmdLine, int showCmd )
{

    ghMainWnd = CreateDialog( hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDD_TXTDLG ), 0, WndProc );
    ShowWindow( ghMainWnd, showCmd );

    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory( &msg, sizeof( MSG ) );

    while( GetMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0 ) )
    {
        if( ghMainWnd == 0 || !IsDialogMessage( ghMainWnd, &msg ) )
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best approach for you to see what is going on is to display the name of the file right before the call. You can do that in the debugger and view what it is and see if it's wrong. It will help you realize if the issue is with the call to the function or something with reading the name. I don't remember that char can be used with GetWindowText (perhaps it's ok in non Unicode).

You also need to add handling to check if the string is empty just in case. Perhaps even verify that the name is valid.